# jQuery Load Data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I used the Load method jquery to change the content of a div.

```
function charger(id,date_fin) {  
    $(document).ready(function () { // On verifie que la page est chargée
        $('#contenue').load('include/detail.php',{id:id,date_fin:date_fin});
    });  
}  
<?php echo '<a href="#" onclick="charger('.$valeur["ID"].','.$d_fin.')">lien</a>';
```

The problem is that I can not recover the value of parameter `$d_fin`,
the date variable, it is not the case for the variable `$id` is integer in the page "detail.php".

Comment: Where does the `$d_fin` value come from? Also, I don't understand the Javascript. You have a call to `ready` that is triggered by a click. Do you think the page will not have loaded before the click happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

}
```

Is only called once when the page is loaded. Try removing it like this:

```
function charger(id,date_fin) {
    $('#contenue').load('include/detail.php',{id:id,date_fin:date_fin});
}  
<?php echo '<a href="#" onclick="charger('.$valeur["ID"].','.$d_fin.')">lien</a>';
```

Comment: Same problem, I can not get the value $date_fin the page detail.php.

Comment: Thank you.  
I found the solution:  
    function chargerSession(id_session) { 
    $('#contenue').load('include/details_session_par_periode.php',{id:id,date_fin:     $("#dfin").val()});
    }